# Android Action bar Sherlock show actions items in dropdown always

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-menu

I have set three action items which am adding to the ABS through menu XML like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_share_app"
        android:icon="@drawable/share_ab"
        android:showAsAction="collapseActionView"
        android:title="@string/menu_share_app"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/share_ab"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/menu_search"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/share_ab"
        android:showAsAction="collapseActionView"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>

</menu>
```

I want to show the search item alwys and the other two in a dropdown, I made the showasaction as "collapseActionView" but am not getting any dropdown.  Here's the sample pic of what am expecting. Thanks! :)[image]

Comment: Aren't you looking for `never`, if you're trying to force the action items into the overflow menu? `collapseActionView` is only applicable to action items that are expandable/collapsable. See also [the documentation for the meaning of the various options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html).

Answer (score 3):

I just changed the code and order.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/share_ab"
        android:showAsAction="always" 
        android:title="@string/menu_search"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_share_app"
        android:icon="@drawable/share_ab"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/menu_share_app"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/share_ab"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>
</menu>
```

If you are having physical menu button (e.g. Nexus S) in your device then the dot line will not show. Even if your AVD emulates a device with has physical menu button then same thing will happen. When you press the Menu button it’ll show up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But i how can force to show the dotted drop down for the devices with hardware menu button.

Comment: @sukarno That I need to explore and see. Will update here if I ever come across it.